# FeedMe plugin multi language import

Tags: plugin-feedme

I would like to import data for fields with multiple locales with the [FeedMe](https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/) plugin. I have to create the JSON feed, so how can I do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found out, what my mistake was: If you import only one locale the fields must not be mandatory, otherwise you get an error about fields (the ones in the other locale) being empty.

Answer (score 1):

Never used the plugin, but it seems like they cover this topic in their [FAQ](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/v2/docs/support/faqs#can-i-import-content-into-a-specific-locale):

> Can I import content into a specific Locale?

Comment: The link is dead, can you update it? Cant find such a FAQ on the new docs at https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/